# Android Java Is it possible to manipulate siblings of a button?

Tags: java, android, xpath

I'm not sure if it's xPath I'm looking for, but I'd like to be able to control an element and its siblings using Java.  I'm good with Javascript, but Java is a different story.

I'd like to be able to manipulate an element that I tap on and its siblings, I've made custom radio buttons and I'd like each set to act like that.  I also want an action to happen (like save a shared preference) when I tap on the radio button, rather than have a secondary button to "save" the option.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:--**>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_user" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_off" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_auto" />
</LinearLayout>
```

If I were to click on `button_off`, I want that button to turn highlighted and the other two (or 3 or 4 or however many I need) buttons to turn 'unselected', exactly like a radio button.  I have multiple sets of these all with different names, so I'd like to be able to do this dynamically.

I know with javascript it would be simple, 4 lines including markup. But I don't know how or what to look into to do this.  I do not want to use `RadioGroup`s or `RadioButton`s for this.  I'd like this to work as it is.

It would be great if I could set this globally so I don't have to set an onClickListenner for every button too, but I'm too new to something that advanced.

Comment: *exactly like a radio button.* why aren't you using the RadioGroup/RadioButton widgets ?

Comment: @Blackbelt I have a lot of code set up this way and the markup for the radio buttons would be the same amount as what I'm doing here I feel.

Comment: Also, because I need an action to happen when I tap on the button.  From the examples I've seen with radiobuttons, I'd have to make a separate button to find the option selected on click of that

Comment: Using RadioGroup handles the selecting and de-selection of radio button where as here you have to have onClickListeners for each button and change the state of each button manually. so it would be far easier to use a radiogroup

Comment: @tyczj, Is it possible to do something when I tap on a radio button (besides manipulate its colors, etc)? Because I need to apply shared preferences on the tap and change settings when I tap on the button, rather than using a second button to "save" the setting

Comment: Radio button also has has an onClicklistener, afterall it is still a `Button`

Comment: @tyczj, Thank you, I'll look into this.